# How to access a Control variable by a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic-variables

I want to use a string value 
like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x= rnd.Next(1, 10);
string ime = "pictureBox" + x.ToString();
ime.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
```

but that doesnt work

Comment: Of course not.. a `string` is not a `PictureBox`.. therefore, a `BackColor` property does not exist.

Comment: No, you don't need to _access a variable by a string_. **You need an array**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434263/c-sharp-use-a-string-to-call-a-variable , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699542/how-can-i-access-to-all-comboboxes-by-for-loop-in-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483912/find-a-control-in-c-sharp-winforms-by-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work for you,

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x= rnd.Next(1, 10);
string ime = "pictureBox" + x.ToString();
((PictureBox)frm.Controls.Find(ime ,true)[0]).BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to use a string like this. You want to get a control with that name and use it like this. You can get a control by name like follows:

```
var pictureBox = myForm.Controls[ime];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating a random name and using it do find the PictureBox with that name, directly pick a random PictureBox:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var pictureBoxes = frm.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
var randomPictureBox = pictureBoxes[rnd.Next(pictureBoxes.Length)];

randomPictureBox.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
```